# Can I use Tsung to load test Socket.io Applications?

Tags: node.js, erlang, socket.io, tsung

I want to use Tsung to load test socket.io application using tsung_ws plugins. However, Socket.io implementation of websocket depends on their javascript.

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Tsung can not execute javascript code, so even if I do not know socket.io I think it's not possible to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for reply.. but why it needs to execute Javascript code? I think if we can somehow pass the socket.io javascript and connection upgrade parameter at the time of handshake it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Tsung now [supports websocket connections](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/user_manual/conf-sessions.html#websocket) via special sessions type

```
<session name="websocket" type="ts_websocket">
```

or by [switching protocols](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/user_manual/conf-sessions.html#mixing-session-type).